# How can I remove '[' and ']' from an awk string?

Tags: regex, awk

I have some regexp control characters that need to be removed from an awk string. How can I replace "[mystring]" with "mystring", if possible without using the first,last index of the original string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `gsub()` function you would do `gsub(/[][]/,"",s)` where `s` is the string to do the replacement, you may want to use `$0` to do the replacemnt on the whole line or `$i` for the i<sup>th</sup> field.

```
$ echo '[mystring]' | awk '{gsub(/[][]/,"",$0)}1'
mystring
```

Comment: `$0` is the default source/destination of `sub`, `gsub`.

Comment: I mean it is not needed to explicitly write into the script.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to know how to write the `sub/gsub` function:

```
kent$  echo '[string]'|awk '{gsub(/[][]/,"")}1'
string
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple sed can do this job:

```
echo "[mystring]" | sed 's/[][]//g'
```

**OUTPUT:**

mystring

Comment: Not a typical `awk`ish solution! ;)

Comment: @TrueY: All other answers are already addressing those typical awk ish nature :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
awk '{  gsub( "\[", "" );gsub( "\]", "" );  print  }'
```

*source: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/awk-delete-%5B-903132/*

Comment: The above is wrong in using 2 gsub()s when 1 will do, and in using double quotes to delimit the RE instead of RE delimiters (/) which in turn would make it necessary to double-escape the [s for it to work properly (i.e. you'd need `"\\["`). As written awk should be giving you a warning message like `escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I have all ready given points to the shortest and most correct answer ;) This just came from the top of my head..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're not looking to get rid of all "[" and "]"s in your input but instead are you only looking to remove them when they occur around the string "mystring", with GNU awk (for gensub()) it's:

```
$ echo "[before] [mystring] [after]" |
  gawk '{$0=gensub(/(.*)\[(mystring)\]/,"\\1\\2","")}1'
[before] mystring [after]
```